# Is it possible to add url to reminder through AppleScript in attachment (preview) style

Tags: applescript, reminders

[image: reminders]

Hi folks, I have an apple script question. Maybe someone know is it possible to add reminder with url in form of preview and not text (on screenshot I want a bottom variant)

Adding url in form of the text is pretty straightforward but I can’t find anything on how to add it in preview style

```bash
osascript << EOF
 tell app "Reminders"
  make new reminder in default list with properties {name:"$name", body:"$link"} 
 end tell
EOF
```

Comment: Any success with that? looking for the same thing :)

Comment: unfortunately no progress :c